org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: unable to invokebrows
OS : Windows server
Language : Java
Chrome version : 124.0
Chrome driver version :125.0
webDriverManager version: 5.4.1

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 122


it's a driver/browser version mismatch.  The error is telling you that you are running v122 of the driver.  (major version must match unless you turn off version checking...)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As of Selenium 4.6, SeleniumManager was added and it automatically takes care of downloading and configuring the appropriate driver for you. So, you no longer need to use a DriverManager or specify the path, etc.
The minimal code needed now is
String url = "https://www.google.com";

driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(url);

